# How should start and end timezone be handled in OData parameters in O365 Calendar REST API v2.0?

Tags: office365, office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

### What I'm trying to achieve

I want to get all events in a user's calendar, sometimes within a specific window between two instants in time, sometimes just all. These events have to be ordered on event start as an instant in time.

### The problem I'm facing

I'm having some issues with using the OData v4 `$filter` and `$orderby` query parameters for filtering and ordering by the event's Start and End. The problem is that since v2.0 of the API, these attributes are objects consisting of a `DateTime` and a `TimeZone` and that the `TimeZone` should be taken into account when filtering/ordering by the `DateTime`.

This snippet is taken from the official docs:

```
{
    "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Users('ddfcd489-628b-40d7-b48b-57002df800e5@1717622f-1d94-4d0c-9d74-709fad664b77')/Events('AAMkAGI28tEyDAAA=')",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"nfZyf7VcrEKLNoU37KWlkQAA/LpDWw==\"",
    "Id": "AAMkAGI28tEyDAAA=",
    "Subject": "Scrum",
    "Start": {
        "DateTime": "2015-11-02T17:00:00",
        "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "End": {
        "DateTime": "2015-11-02T17:30:00",
        "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    ...
}
```

I could filter on `Start/DateTime` and `End/DateTime`, but **that doesn't take timezone offsets into account**. Same goes for ordering by `Start/DateTime`:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/users/user@example.org/events/?$filter=End/DateTime%20gt%202016-12-11T00:00:00&$orderby=Start/DateTime
```

Trying to order by just `Start` results in an error, which tells me I can't order on a non-primitive attribute.

The timezones I receive in the responses all seem to be UTC, regardless which timezone I specify when creating the event. However, the docs show 'Pacific Stardard Time', so I probably can't assume all events are always converted to UTC.

### Why this problem didn't exist in the v1.0 API

In v1.0 of the API, `Start` and `End` were still of the (primitive) `datetimeoffset`, and `StartTimeZone` and `EndTimeZone` were separate attributes, so the problem didn't exist by then. `Start` and `End` contained an offset, so I could filter on these attributes and order by them while just ignoring the `StartTimeZone` and `EndTimeZone` attributes.

### Using /calendarview instead of /events

I'm aware of the existence of the `/calendarview` endpoint, which allows me to specify a window to retrieve events for. However, using this endpoint also implies that I receive all occurences (in which I'm not interested) of events instead of single events and series masters. That's one of the reasons why I'd prefer to use the regular `/events` endpoint.

Comment: There are two ampersands instead of %27 (single quotes) surrounding the datetime you are filtering by. Checking the documentation, it should look like this: /api/v2.0/users/user@example.org/events/?$filter=End/DateTime%20gt%20%272016-12-11T00:00:00%27&$orderby=Start/DateTime

Comment: The first ampersand is a typo, so I removed it now, thanks. The second one indicates the next query parameter, so it needs to be there. The docs show there shouldn't be quotes around a timestamp: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#Filter.

Comment: thanks for the correction, however here is what this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#OdataQueryParams documentation says as an example, api/v2.0/me/events?$filter=Start/DateTime%20ge%20%272016-04-01T08:00%27 .%27 is a single quote. However I see many examples without, so I assume  you are correct

Comment: Uhm, this is going to sound stupid, but could you try $orderby=Start\DateTime instead? (note the forward slash is now a backslash)

Comment: To be more clear, my problem is not that filtering on `Start/DateTime` does not work, but that the timezone is not taken into account, because afaik every event can have a different `Start/TimeZone`. The DateTime doesn't have a real meaning without its TimeZone.

Comment: Sorry, focused on the wrong issue then. $orderby=Start/DateTime,Start/TimeZone (or TimeZone, then DateTime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the prefer time zone header to get the response in your desired time zone

`Prefer: outlook.timezone="Eastern Standard Time"`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! This feature is unfortunately not documented in the official API docs. That's why I didn't find it earlier. It's documented in this Microsoft blog, however: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/10/14/outlook-rest-api-changes-to-beta-endpoint-part-ii/